Plotting of random dataPoints and subsequent concave hull of Clusters points are offset in SwiftUI Charts
       var id: String { return "\(x), \(y)" }
       var x: Double = .random(in: Double(0.0)..<Double(1000.0))
       var y: Double = .random(in: Double(0.0)..<Double(500.0))
    
       func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
           hasher.combine(id)
           hasher.combine(x)
           hasher.combine(y)
       }
   }

extension MyPoint {
    static var data: [MyPoint] {
        return (0...200).map { _ in
            MyPoint()
        }
    }
}

struct MyPoints: Identifiable {
    
    let name: String
    var points: [MyPoint]
    let index: Int
    var id: String { "\(index): " + name }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
        hasher.combine(points)
    }
}

    var dataPoints: [MyPoint] = MyPoint.data
    @State var hullDataPoints: [MyPoint] = []
    @State var clustersHullDataPoints: [MyPoints] = []

    let hull = Hull()

    let colors: [Color] = [.purple, .cyan, .orange, .yellow, .green, .mint, .brown, .indigo, .pink, .teal, .gray]
    

    var body: some View {
        Chart(content: {
            ForEach(dataPoints) { point in
                PointMark(x: CGFloat(point.x), y: .value("y", point.y))
                    .foregroundStyle(.red)
                    .symbol(Circle().strokeBorder(lineWidth: 1.5))
            }
            /*ForEach(hullDataPoints) { point in
                LineMark(x: .value("x", point.x), y: .value("y", point.y))
                    .foregroundStyle(.blue)
                    .symbol(Circle().strokeBorder(lineWidth: 1.5))
            }*/

            ForEach(clustersHullDataPoints) { cluster in
                ForEach(cluster.points) { point in
                    LineMark(x: .value("x", point.x), y: .value("y", point.y))
                        .foregroundStyle(colors[cluster.index])
                }
                
            }
        })
        .chartXScale(domain: [0, 1000])
        .chartYScale(domain: [0, 500])
        .chartXAxis {
            AxisMarks(values: .automatic(desiredCount: 10))
        }
        .chartYAxis {
            AxisMarks(values: .automatic(desiredCount: 5))
        }
        .task {
            await calcHull()
            await calcGMMClusters()
        }
        
    }

calcHull calculates hullDataPoints(not shown for clarity), calcGMMClusters calculates clusters and then clustersHullDataPoints.
Notice as the x values increase, there is an offset to position of LineMarks & PointMarks. Also why are each boundary line for each cluster picking up a point from the previous cluster(when I check the cluster boundary points, this extra point is not there). I’ve asked each cluster to use a different colour and that doesn’t happen.
What am I missing?

Using DGCharts framework was able to produce correctly


https://github.com/swainwri/ASyncTesting.git has the project
